# Connect points in DHTMLX scatter chart

Tags: scatter-plot, dhtmlx

I have about 500 XY points which I would like represent as line using DHTMLXChart. Apparently the only suitable chart (scatter) do not allowing to do it. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you ABSOLUTELY bound to using Scatter Charts from DHTMLXChart? Google Charts has scatter graphs which would be a better alternative.

Comment: Why would a DHTMLX line chart not work? What is it about the scatter chart that you need?

Comment: @CullenJ Line chart does not respect Xaix scale. After long discussion DHTMLX support offered me some solution to force line chart to do it http://forum.dhtmlx.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=37019&start=10 but I did not try it for large amounts of data.

Comment: @Raptus not absolutely, but I do not want to add another library until it is absolutely necessarily

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way to do this.

You could use line chart with markers:

[Example](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxChart/samples/05_line_chart/07_legend.html)

Comment: not directly see this discussion forum.dhtmlx.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=37019&start=10

Answer (score 0):

Ok on that confirmation you're not bound to a DHTMLX, I would go with [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/) it's based on opinion, but more importantly on **functionality**.

The Google Charts API is very easy to work with as it takes raw Javascript data and applies it to the chart and that data may be shoved into multidimensional arrays or as I prefer, JSON Data.

Additionally the Google Charts API has what you are after which is located at https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart or alternatively...
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/scatterchart

P.S. It may be a hefty documentation to read, but learning Google Charts API pays dividends and this would Replace DHTMLX instead of being an additional plugin.

Hope that helps.